# URL syntax for Youtube videos in fullscreen WITHOUT embedding video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I like to be able to share youtube music video URLs that automatically start in full-screen.  The only way I know how to do this is by sharing the video as an embedded video; such as:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/oRdxUFDoQe0?autoplay=1
```

Unfortunately, as you can see, that does not work on copyrighted videos.  So.. what's the trick to playback youtube videos automatically in fullscreen without embedding it?  I tried the below URL format, but that didn't work either.  Surely there has to be a way to do this>

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRdxUFDoQe0&fs=1
```